# R Shiny: Dynamic column layout to prevent whitespace

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I have a shiny dashboard app with a box. The box contains two elements, a slider and a switch. They should be displayed in one row.
[image]
When I zoom out, I do not want to get additional whitespace at the end of the row, but rather let the slider take up more space. 
[image]

It seems like `column()` is not the right way to layout my app, however I did not find a way to get my elements in one row without `column()`.

How can I get the elements in one row and let the switch take up no more space than it needs?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)



ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(),
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                    body = dashboardBody(  column(12, box(width="100%", 
column(width=9, sliderInput("hi", label = "I like sliding", min = 1, max = 
42, value = 20,width="100%")),
                                                         column(width=3, 
switchInput("ho", label ="Switch me tonight", width="100%")))))
)


server <- function(input, output) { 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Play around with the `width` in the style argument below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(header = dashboardHeader(),
                    sidebar = dashboardSidebar(),
                    body = dashboardBody(box(width=12, 
                                               div(style="display: inline-block; width: 92%;",sliderInput("hi", label = "I like sliding", min = 1, max = 42, value = 20)),
                                               div(style="display: inline-block; width: 7%;",switchInput("ho", label ="Switch me tonight"))


                    ))
)


server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however the switch is not in the box when I zoom in with your width parameters. When I use different parameters, I get the whitespace. Can I align the switchInput somehow to the end of the row? (and maybe later also center it vertically?)